# How to open fancybox using map link

Tags: javascript, html, fancybox

The link was given to a jpg file using map.

```
<map name="Map" id="Map">
<area shape="rect" coords="350,350,350,350" href="......" target="_new" />
</map>
```

how can i open fancybox using that link?

Comment: I want to open fancybox while clicking a map in a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use this script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#Map area").fancybox({
  // API options here
 }); // fancybox
});//ready
```

Make sure you add the right API options for the version you are using (if your `href` targets an image, you may not need any)

If using v1.3.4 check http://fancybox.net/api.

For v2.x check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Map area').click(function(e){     // On click of <area> tag
    var href = $(this).attr('href'); // Get the href param 
    $.fancybox({                     // Open fancybox
        'href'   : href,
        'width'  : 350,
        'height' : 'auto'
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```