# Fancybox 1.3.4 Image Gallery from Image Map?

Tags: javascript, html, fancybox, gallery, imagemap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to open fancybox using map link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412483/how-to-open-fancybox-using-map-link)

I have found out how to use the links from imagemaps to display single images using Fancybox. I integrated into my site successfully. But, whatever I do, I cannot make it to display galleries.

I'm using the code below to display single images from an ImageMap.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*  Tek imaj */
        $("a#fbox").fancybox({
            'overlayShow'   : false,
            'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
            'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
            'titlePosition' : 'inside'
        });
    });

</script>   
     <script type="text/javascript">
/* Image Map'den */
    //<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
    $('map > area.fbox').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    var type = $(this).attr('rel');
    $.fancybox({
        'title': title,
        'titlePosition': 'inside',
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
        'href' : url,
        'type' : type
    });
});
});//]]>  
</script>
```

These are the scripts, and this is the HTML.

```
<area shape="rect" coords="417,80,477,93" href="blabla.jpg" class="fbox" title="more blablabla" rel="image" />
```